# How can I style the legend of jquery-mobile radio buttons like a list divider

Tags: jquery-mobile

Putting radio buttons in a `fieldset` with `data-role="controlgroup"`, jquery-mobile renders them like an inset list, but the legend is simply text. I would like the legend to look like the list dividers of a list view.

So instead of this:

[image: current situation]

I would like something like that:

[image: what I would need]

Comment: Could you please setup a JSFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put the radiogroup inside of a listview, and use the listdivider style for the title. To get to a result which is similar to what you demonstrated, you need to remove some padding, margins and borders.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zdMhF/

The code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Choose a pet:</li>
<li style="padding:0;border:0;">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="margin:0;">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
             <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this is almost it. If we could get rid of the rounded upper corners of the first option, it would be perfect.

Comment: You can do that by adding to the style for the label: ` <label for="radio-choice-1" style="border-radius:0;">Cat</label>'. See this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdMhF/1/

Comment: Great, now it's perfect. Thanks a lot.